# Firestore - Add field on Document that also has a subcollection

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add/update a field on a document that also has a subcollection.

[image]

On console it seems possible but trying to do it in different ways I can't do it.

For example when I try:

`fb.db.collection('wani').doc('python').update({field:'value});`

I get a "No document to update" error.

I can't find how to do this on documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with subcollections.  Your code is trying to [update()](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference.update) a document with the path "wani/python".  That document doesn't exist.  You can tell because the console is showing the document ID "python" in italics.  Updates against documents that don't exist will give you that error.  (A document doesn't have to exist in order to have subcollections nested underneath it.)

If you want to update a document, you will need to first create it using [set()](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference.update).  If you want to update a document OR create it if it doesn't exist, you will have to use `set()` with the merge option as described in the linked API documentation.

Comment: If you want to create the document if it doesn't exist yet, but update it if it already happens to exist, be sure to pass in the `, merge=True` option as shown in the second snippet here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you.